# How to catch connection lost in avcodec_decode_video2?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using android ffmpeg port and i have native crash while playing and connection lost:

```
07-03 16:06:45.036      831-831/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ Build: samsung/hltexx/hlte:4.4.2/KOT49H/N9005XXUENA7:user/release-keys
    Hardware: MSM8974
    Revision: 8
    Bootloader: N9005XXUENA7
    Radio: unknown
    Kernel: Linux version 3.4.0-348029 (dpi@SWDC3316) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jan 11 09:45:51 KST 2014
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hltexx/hlte:4.4.2/KOT49H/N9005XXUENA7:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '8'
    pid: 21599, tid: 25027, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> com.company.project <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0037000f
    r0 8ef40b10  r1 00000002  r2 8ef40b0c  r3 00000000
    r4 825d0270  r5 79b51e20  r6 00370007  r7 002a001f
    r8 8ef40b0c  r9 79b10160  sl 8ef40bd8  fp 79c62cf8
    ip 00000000  sp 8ef40ae4  lr 7c0ed1db  pc 7be277fc  cpsr 280f0030
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  3fd34413509f79fb  d5  40c3880000000000
    d6  426d1a94a2000000  d7  42a0c6f7a0b5ed8d
    d8  3f13bcd3441bd127  d9  461c40000000168b
    d10 00000000441bd127  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 00240014003e000e  d17 0028001c00340004
    d18 0021001100390009  d19 002d001900310001
    d20 00270017003d000d  d21 002a001f00370007
    d22 00220012003a000a  d23 002e001a00320002
    d24 0202020202020202  d25 fefefefefefefefe
    d26 40e8fd171d2bf551  d27 402305681ecd4aa1
    d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 007f007f007f007f
    d30 ffffffffffffffff  d31 4000000000000000
    scr 88000012
    backtrace:
    #00  pc 001217fc  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-178/libffmpeg-neon.so (av_packet_get_side_data+11)
    #01  pc 003e71d7  /data/app-lib/com.company.project-178/libffmpeg-neon.so (avcodec_decode_video2+118)
    stack:
    8ef40aa4  00000000
    8ef40aa8  00000001
    8ef40aac  00000000
    8ef40ab0  0000a09f
    8ef40ab4  00000000
    8ef40ab8  00000001
    8ef40abc  4029abd9  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::Surface::queueBuffer(ANativeWindowBuffer*, int)+300)
    8ef40ac0  79afa958
    8ef40ac4  4002bf80
    8ef40ac8  00000002
    8ef40acc  00000000
    8ef40ad0  00000000
    8ef40ad4  00000000
    8ef40ad8  79b51fd8
    8ef40adc  825d0270
    8ef40ae0  79b51e20
    #00  8ef40ae4  825d0270
    ........  ........
    #01  8ef40ae4  825d0270
    8ef40ae8  79b51e20
    8ef40aec  8ef40b10  [stack:25027]
    8ef40af0  8192cfc0
    8ef40af4  8ef40b0c  [stack:25027]
    8ef40af8  00000001
    8ef40afc  00000000
    8ef40b00  00000000
    8ef40b04  00000000
    8ef40b08  00000000
    8ef40b0c  00000000
    8ef40b10  003f000f
    8ef40b14  00250015
    8ef40b18  00350005
    8ef40b1c  0029001d
    8ef40b20  00390009
    memory near r0:
    8ef40af0 8192cfc0 8ef40b0c 00000001 00000000
    8ef40b00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    8ef40b10 003f000f 00250015 00350005 0029001d
    8ef40b20 00390009 00210011 00310001 002d0019
    8ef40b30 003d000d 00270017 00370007 002a001f
    8ef40b40 003a000a 00220012 00320002 002e001a
    8ef40b50 003e000e 00240014 00340004 0028001c
    8ef40b60 4029a577 825d0270 79b51e20 7a049803
    8ef40b70 8192cfc0 787bcf70 7b409008 79ded900
    8ef40b80 7b409008 7a02c783 1d2bf551 40e8fd17
    8ef40b90 7f62b6ae 3ff07dd9 6f177a70 40e8fc9f
    8ef40ba0 1d2bf551 40e8fd17 7f62b6ae 3ff07dd9
    8ef40bb0 ea5ecf87 0000000b 7b4c48f4 00000000
    8ef40bc0 0000001c 79afa598 798ed350 0000000b
    8ef40bd0 000fba45 00000000 00000000 00000001
    8ef40be0 000f4240 000002c0 53b52b34 9adb02b9
    memory near r2:
    8ef40aec 8ef40b10 8192cfc0 8ef40b0c 00000001
    8ef40afc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    8ef40b0c 00000000 003f000f 00250015 00350005
    8ef40b1c 0029001d 00390009 00210011 00310001
    8ef40b2c 002d0019 003d000d 00270017 00370007
    8ef40b3c 002a001f 003a000a 002200
07-03 16:06:45.036      831-831/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ processName:com.company.project
07-03 16:06:45.036      831-831/? D/CrashAnrDetector﹕ broadcastEvent : com.company.project SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
07-03 16:06:45.036     831-1281/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 24245:com.google.android.apps.magazines/u0a131 (adj 15): empty #31
07-03 16:06:45.046      831-831/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1468 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.broadcastEvent:296 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.processDropBoxEntry:254 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector.access$100:60 com.android.server.analytics.data.collection.application.CrashAnrDetector$1.onReceive:102
07-03 16:06:45.066  25171-25171/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
07-03 16:06:45.066  25171-25171/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2_0013
07-03 16:06:45.066  25171-25171/? I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
07-03 16:06:45.116   1049-31569/? D/KeyguardViewMediator﹕ setHidden false
07-03 16:06:45.116   1049-31569/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
07-03 16:06:45.116    1049-1049/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged(1)
07-03 16:06:45.166     831-1281/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{44ddb5e8 u0 SurfaceView}
07-03 16:06:45.166   1049-11393/? D/KeyguardViewMediator﹕ setHidden false
07-03 16:06:45.166   1049-11393/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
07-03 16:06:45.166    1049-1049/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor﹕ handleKeyguardVisibilityChanged(1)
07-03 16:06:45.166      831-841/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.company.project (pid 21599) (adj 0) has died.
```

How can i fix it - catch exceptions or any other solution?